# Can't find maven 'update dependencies' menu on Eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I used to have 'update dependencies' menu in project right click menu, when I was using eclipse helios.

But from when I update the eclipse & m2e plugin, I can't find 'update dependencies' menu anymore.

whre is 'update dependencies' menu? or is there any alternative?

I'm using m2e v1.1.0.20120530-0009, by the way

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The menu entry is now "Update Project". In that wizard you find a checkbox "Update dependencies".

Answer (score 5):

And now "Update Project" gives you option to do "Update dependencies" , "Update project configuration", "clean project" in one click.