# android-maven-plugin: How to update dependencies?

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2e

Let's say I have a platform version of 4 in my pom.xml but I'd like to change it to version 7 or similar changes. How can I update the dependencies of my project? If it is an usual Eclipse Java project, I could execute eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse to "refresh" the whole project but the android plugin doesn't have any goals like this. If I would execute eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse, the project seems to be translated to a real Java project (not Android). Maven->Update Project doesn't help too. At work my Eclipse Indigo has the options "Update project configuration" and "update dependencies". Here, I don't have this. Maybe these settings are combined to "Update Project" in the latest version of m2e or something.

So what's the proper way to update dependencies?

I'm using Eclipse Juno, m2e 1.1.0, android m2e 0.4.2.

Comment: Yes in the latest version it is now called Update Project.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715121/cant-find-maven-update-dependencies-menu-on-eclipse-juno

Comment: This doesn't help. Update dependencies is greyed out in the Wizzard. Moreover I don't think that this would help. I guess I need the project to rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is right click on the project -> Properties -> Android -> choose Project Build target.

And there is already an issue so that m2e-android can handle this in future: https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/109