# Spring-data Mongodb JUnit error

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, junit, spring-data

I'm working on a spring MVC project using Spring data with Mongodb.
I just created the entities and did the configuration. Then once testing with JUnit i got an error that i couldn't fix. Can anyone help me with this please .
Here is my spring configuration file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="AgenceAviationDB" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

These are my maven dependencies:

```
    spring-core 4.2.1.RELEASE
    mongo-java-driver 2.12.1
    spring-data-mongodb 1.4.2.RELEASE
    spring-context 4.2.1.RELEASE
    junit 4.7
```

Here is one of my entities:

```
package com.pfa.agenceDaviation.entities;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
@Document
public class Passager implements Serializable{
@Id
private String id;
private String nomP;
private String adresseP;
private String nTelephoneP;
//setters getters and constructors
```

This is my test class:

```
package com.pfa.agenceDaviation;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext; 
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
public class testDAO {
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
}

@Test
public void test() {
    try {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("ApplicationContext.xml");
           MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");  
            assertTrue(true);

    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    assertTrue(e.getMessage(),false);
    }
    }
    }
```

And this is the error i'm getting :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParserConfiguration.<init>(Lorg/springframework/expression/spel/SpelCompilerMode;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.<init>(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:98)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
at org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext.<init>(GenericXmlApplicationContext.java:70)
at com.pfa.agenceDaviation.testDAO.test(testDAO.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Can anyone help me with this please. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Could you form you code properly ?There's an errors!

Comment: what's not ok with my code ?

Answer (score 0):

- ran mvn dependency:tree
- Pay attention to your spring-data-mongodb dependencies

You will notice that spring-data-mongodb is using spring version - 4.2.1.RELEASE
Here is the proof - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb/1.4.2.RELEASE

So, possible solution - update your spring dependecies to 4.2.1

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Next step, you need to check is you really need to store **spring-core** and **spring-context**.If you really need them - just exclude those dependencies from **spring-data-mongodb**

Comment: Let's think.One moment

Comment: I updated my answer - please check it, you need to update your spring to 4.2.1.RELEASE, not 4.2.0.RELEASE.If it works - please vote for me

Comment: Are you sure that you use spring 4.2.1.RELEASE?Maybe you forgot to update your dependencies.It should work!

Comment: What IDE are u using ?)

Comment: i'm using Eclipse Kepler. I updated spring-context and spring-core to 4.2.1 like you said.

Comment: Do like in image http://qualipso.gforge.inria.fr/Install/images/full/maven-update-dependencies.png

Comment: You have old dependencies in your project and you need to update maven to use new dependencies

Comment: I don't have that option in the version i'm using of Eclipse Kepler. I tried the "maven clean" option though, it says :  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

Comment: Man, if you do mvn clean, then it will clear all your target folder.

Comment: I only have maven build maven, maven clean maven install and maven test options. Do you think that the problem might be with the slf4j api ?

Comment: I really think that you are not doing what I ask.

Comment: i am though, except for the maven clean install because i do not have that option.

Comment: Read this article about update dependencies
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715121/cant-find-maven-update-dependencies-menu-on-eclipse-juno

Comment: i have the update project option with update dependencies option checked, already did that, it's not working.

Comment: What is shows ?What is not working?Man, you are not providing enough information and expect to get some correct answer!!!!Attach screenshot, show your console logs.

Comment: Ok i just updated my post and put the dependencies i have on my project now.

Comment: I'm sorry i can't attach sceershots, i don't have enough reputation. But what information do i need to provide. After following your instructions i'm still getting the same error .

Comment: Okay, we can try in another way - can you push part of this project to github ?So I will clone it and try to find out. That would be the fastest way :)